# How to quickly work on a single class of a big GUI C# project?

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio

So here's the problem. I have a massive C# project in Visual Studio. It has a big GUI that manages a large number of classes.

In one of the form windows, there is a bunch of textboxes. The user fills in the data and then clicks a button and then my class is created to do whatever.

How do I work on and quickly run this class, without having to open the GUI, navigate to it, etc, so that I can quickly test and code this new class?

Comment: This question is incredibly broad, can you please give a specific example to narrow it down?

Comment: @Matthew I'm working on a class and I'd like to run it directly.

Comment: What's to stop you from doing `var myClass = new MyClass()`?

Comment: @User: A C# project in Visual Basic? How does that work?

Comment: @Matthew I'd have to comment out everything else at runtime?

Comment: @JacquesB Visual Studio, I meant

Comment: If you're having trouble testing a class on its own, it means that your classes are too tightly coupled.  There are many ways to reduce that coupling, and in so doing, increase your ability to test.  Utilizing a UI pattern such as MVP or MVVM is one such way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a unit test framework, like NUnit or the one built into Visual Studio. Then you can write small test cases which exercise exactly the parts of the code you want to try out.

Comment: What is the one built in called?

Comment: MSTest is built into Visual Studio. Note that NUnit and other frameworks will have plugins to integrate with VS so you can use anyone you like.